# WPF: How to make two controls (list views) share whole available space between them?

Tags: wpf, listview, resize, panel, space

I have two list views (vertically aligned) which might have various number of items. I'd like them to share space proportionally when needed (this I can achieve with regular grid and *) but when one list view doesn't have many items to show I would like other list view to fill the whole space. And vice versa.

Tried different things but could not achieve this behavior.

For instance with grid I can specify * and * (or other proportions) but it means that half of the space will be empty if one of list views does not have any items (and another has tons of them).

Is there a way to achieve this? Do I need to implement my own Panel for this or there is another (simpler) way to do it?

Thank you!
Zaki

Comment: What would it look like when none of the list views have enough items to fill the whole space?

Comment: Then it would be okay to have empty space. My goal is to use whole space when it is needed...

Update: top listview show dock to top and botton to bottom...

Comment: If it's okay to have empty space below list views, just put them into `<StackPanel Orientation="Vertial">`

Comment: Not sure I understand how it would work. I believe if the first list view has lots of items it will take the whole space available. I need to share space 50/50 in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just would like to share the final version which does what I wanted. Thank you to **torvin** for providing the right direction, appreciate quick and valuable response!

=================================================================

Implemented resizing of main window in such a way that:

1. If there is unused space than any of list views can use it (so, no unused area with scroll bar at the same time)
2. If there is not enough space then bottom control takes at least 100 pixel and/or top controls takes at least Height – 100 pixels
3. Top control docks to top and bottom control docks to bottom

=================================================================

```
/// <summary>The two children effecient panel.</summary>
public class TwoChildrenEffecientPanel : Panel
{
    #region Constants and Fields

    /// <summary>The bottom child min size.</summary>
    private const double BottomChildMinSize = 110;

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    /// <summary>The arrange override.</summary>
    /// <param name="arrangeSize">The arrange size.</param>
    /// <returns>The <see cref="Size"/>.</returns>
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
    {
        Debug.Assert(this.InternalChildren.Count == 2, "This custom panel supports only two children.");

        UIElement top = this.InternalChildren[0];
        var topRect = new Rect(arrangeSize);
        topRect.Height = top.DesiredSize.Height;
        top.Arrange(topRect);

        UIElement bottom = this.InternalChildren[1];
        var bottomRect = new Rect(arrangeSize);
        bottomRect.Height = bottom.DesiredSize.Height;
        bottomRect.Y = arrangeSize.Height - bottomRect.Height;
        bottom.Arrange(bottomRect);

        return arrangeSize;
    }

    /// <summary>The measure override.</summary>
    /// <param name="constraint">The constraint.</param>
    /// <returns>The <see cref="Size"/>.</returns>
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        Debug.Assert(this.InternalChildren.Count == 2, "This custom panel supports only two children.");

        // First measure desired size of all children.
        var availableSize = new Size(constraint.Width, double.PositiveInfinity);
        foreach (UIElement ui in this.InternalChildren)
        {
            ui.Measure(availableSize);
        }

        // Put constraints only if space is not enough
        double totalHeight = this.InternalChildren.OfType<UIElement>().Sum(x => x.DesiredSize.Height);
        if (totalHeight > constraint.Height)
        {
            UIElement top = this.InternalChildren[0];
            UIElement bottom = this.InternalChildren[1];

            if (bottom.DesiredSize.Height < BottomChildMinSize)
            {
                // If the second control needs less than it can get then put contraint only on the first one
                top.Measure(new Size(constraint.Width, Math.Max(constraint.Height - bottom.DesiredSize.Height, 0)));
            }
            else if (top.DesiredSize.Height < constraint.Height - BottomChildMinSize)
            {
                // If the first control needs less than it can get then put contraint only on the second one
                bottom.Measure(new Size(constraint.Width, Math.Max(constraint.Height - top.DesiredSize.Height, 0)));
            }
            else
            {
                top.Measure(new Size(constraint.Width, Math.Max(constraint.Height - BottomChildMinSize, 0)));
                bottom.Measure(new Size(constraint.Width, BottomChildMinSize));
            }
        }

        double maxWidth = this.InternalChildren.OfType<UIElement>().Max(x => x.DesiredSize.Width);
        return new Size(Math.Min(constraint.Width, maxWidth), Math.Min(constraint.Height, totalHeight));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, try this code:

```
class MyPanel : Panel
{
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        // first measuring desired size of children
        var availableSize = new Size(constraint.Width, double.PositiveInfinity);
        foreach (UIElement ui in InternalChildren)
            ui.Measure(availableSize);

        var totalHeight = InternalChildren.OfType<UIElement>().Sum(x => x.DesiredSize.Height);

        // now resizing children within constraint
        var factor = (totalHeight == 0 ? 1.0 : constraint.Height / totalHeight);
        foreach (UIElement ui in InternalChildren)
            ui.Measure(new Size(constraint.Width, ui.DesiredSize.Height * factor));

        var maxWidth = InternalChildren.OfType<UIElement>().Max(x => x.DesiredSize.Width);
        return new Size(Math.Min(constraint.Width, maxWidth), Math.Min(constraint.Height, totalHeight));
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
    {
        // aligning children vertically 

        var totalHeight = InternalChildren.OfType<UIElement>().Sum(ui => ui.DesiredSize.Height);
        var y = 0.0;
        var rect = new Rect(arrangeSize);

        foreach (UIElement ui in InternalChildren)
        {
            rect.Y += y;
            y = ui.DesiredSize.Height;
            rect.Height = y;
            ui.Arrange(rect);
        }

        return arrangeSize;
    }
}
```

This panel would arrange children vertically and give children vertical space proportionally to their desired height, but won't allow them take more space than available.

So, if, for example, you have 200px height available, first list view wants 150px, and second wants 100px, they will be scaled down to 120px + 80px == 200px

Comment: (in my solution I added a constraint for having only two children and also used own custom proportion rather than relying on factor based on content {the latter results in not good behavior when there 1000 vs. 10 items}). Thank you again.